# Keras Creating CNN Model "The added layer must be an instance of class Layer"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Input, Dense

def create_model():

    def add_conv_block(model, num_filters):

        model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, 3, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        return model

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=(32, 32, 3)))

    model = add_conv_block(model, 32)
    model = add_conv_block(model, 64)
    model = add_conv_block(model, 128)

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNmSz.png)

Comment: Just tested it, didn't get an error. Please elaborate.

Comment: TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)

Comment: https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/a9a63605-03bf-4fb2-83fd-c43e7557b393/view?access_token=2e9b7d33525b2137ebd2ca26f2343ccb9e4c6ae22d633ac3d59ef3f8ba05bf50

Comment: added the link to the file  please help it's rhyme guided project but Still getting Errors

Comment: The code is fine, either in TF2 or TF1 I can get it to work, I think there is a messup in the import, instead of using `model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()` can you try `model = Sequential()` and import = > `from tensorflow.keras.model  import Sequential` ?

Comment: @Aymal do you continue to receive the error?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Yes i am still receiving the same error.

Comment: I provide an answer don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is related to the TF version... however I suggest u this implementation. In this way, you can specify the input_shape in the first layer of the sequential model and override the problem

```
def create_model():

    def add_conv_block(model, num_filters, input_shape=None):

        if input_shape:
            model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=input_shape))
        else:
            model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))

        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, 3, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        return model

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model = add_conv_block(model, 32, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
    model = add_conv_block(model, 64)
    model = add_conv_block(model, 128)

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `InputLayer` instead of `Input`. `InputLayer` is meant to be used with `Sequential` models. You can also omit the `InputLayer` entirely and specify `input_shape` in the first layer of the sequential model.

`Input` is meant to be used with the TensorFlow Keras functional API, not the sequential API.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, InputLayer, Dense

def create_model():

    def add_conv_block(model, num_filters):

        model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Conv2D(num_filters, 3, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        return model

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(InputLayer((32, 32, 3)))

    model = add_conv_block(model, 32)
    model = add_conv_block(model, 64)
    model = add_conv_block(model, 128)

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()
```